# How to resolve Apex CPU time limited exceeded while running the batch?

Tags: apex, batch, webservices

I have a batch class

> Batch apex:

```
public void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List<List<String>> records) {
 Rfleet_GetValues_DzC2G prodData = new Rfleet_GetValues_DzC2G(); 
 List<product2> listProd = new List<product2>();
 List<product2> listProd1 = new List<product2>();
 for(List<String> d:records){ 
     List<String> lsScpversioncode= prodData.getVersionScpCode(d[6]);  
     List<String> lsScpversion= prodData.getVersionScpLabel(d[8]);
     List<String> lsC2gversionCode= prodData.getC2GVersionCode(d[9]);
     List<String> lsSCRversion= prodData.getVersionScrCode(d[9]);

     for(String strversioncode:lsScpversioncode)
     {
       for(String strSCRversion:lsSCRversion){
           for(String strScpversion:lsScpversion ){
             for(string strC2gversionCode:lsC2gversionCode){

                 Product2 newProd=new product2(); 
                 brand=d[4];  
                 newProd.ProductCode=strversioncode;
                 newProd.CurrencyIsoCode=getCurrency;
                 newProd.Description=getcountrycode+'-'+brand+'-'+strversioncode;

                 newProd.name=getcountrycode+'-'+strScpversion;
                 if(brand=='APL03'){brand='Reanult';}
                 if(brand=='APL05')
                   {System.debug('brand<<<<<<<<<<'+brand);brand='Dacia';}
                 newProd.Brand__c=brand;
                 newProd.Country_code__c=getcountrycode;

                 newProd.SCP_code__c=strSCRversion;
                 newProd.SCP_Label__c=strScpversion;
                 newProd.IsActive=true;
                 listProd1.add(newProd);
              }   
            }
         }    

   }         
    }

     insert listProd1 ;

}
```

the parameter "record" in execute batch contains the list of values.I passed some of list values to the "Rfleet_GetValues_DzC2G" apex class and stored the values in list.I want to insert all data in the Product object.But am getting the error.How can i resolve it ??Please help me out.thanks in advance.

Comment: You have 4 nested loops in your code. This is the reason behind the CPU limit

Comment: Yeah...But to refine this..Could you please provide me some solutions

Comment: Infact its 5 ...not just 4 ...Quick fix reduce batch size but permanent fix consider using Maps and avoid loops